# Resource.Id is not finding the definition for my button

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, layout, visual-studio-2019

When i use FindViewById(Resource.Id.) is not finding the button that i need to use.

i've already tried saving, building and rebuilding the solution and the project, and nothing seems to work

my layout is this:

[Layout Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xz3pW.png)
And my main code is the following

[Main Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OUc9t.png)

Comment: check the update,could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure layout code is in the main xml layout file or in a file that is referenced with include in the main layout file.

Comment: Yes that is in the main xml file

Answer (score 0):

1. Ensure that the `Resource` is your `namespace.Resource`
2. Ignore the error message of VS, continue to build (it's vs tools's problem,always notice id can
   not find, but you can still run)
3. If still not work after the above two points, delete the content inside the  **Resources/Resource.Designer.cs** file, and then rebuild (delete the contents of the file, not delete the file)

update:make sure the axml file **BuildAction** is **AndroidResource** like this:

[image]

Comment: @HayromBlanco the third method also could not work ?you try to create a new project see if still have the error